# How can i read a particular terminal output from python as input in another script

Tags: python, terminal, stdout, stdin

I have python script output like this

```
client:"A"
Total number of keys discovered: 22
Execution finished. Total time: 0:00:05.361506
Key: 'caJ8ArNRvefgdfgbdhfdbfdbf' | Cannot flip key due to  
feature1 being enabled
Key: 'caixF0Nmdfjdfdbfdgdbgdnmjdfs' | Cannot flip key due to  
feature1 being enabled
Total keys: 22 | Keys that Application can serve: 20 | Keys that Application can't serve: 2
Execution finished. Total time: 0:00:33.796226
client:"B"
Total number of keys discovered: 13
Execution finished. Total time: 0:00:05.539271
Total keys: 13 | Keys that Application can serve: 13 | Keys that Application can't serve: 0
Execution finished. Total time: 0:00:20.573984
```

I want to use "Keys that Application can't serve: 2" this number in a python script I want something that helps me to grep the number of keys that cant be served and use it as a variable in my script

Comment: It is unclear on what you need. It sounds like you can use your Python script to keep track of which keys "can't serve" and then use it in your script. So it's not clear on why you would need to use grep when you already have Python.

Comment: Ya, I want something like grep but in python, I need to run a python script for failed clients. So I am trying to figure out a way just to keep track of failed clients from stdout

Comment: In that case, I feel like you can just write a simple `if` conditional statement to trigger when you run/print out "Cannot flip key due to..." and count the number of times to encounter this condition. Then from there you can print out the statement "Keys that Application can't serve: X" where X is the number of elements. Are you not able to edit the Python script that outputs this output above?

Comment: No, i don't have access to edit this script. I just can use its output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume you have that output as a text file.

```sh
$ cat output.txt
# client:"A"
# Total number of keys discovered: 22
# Execution finished. Total time: 0:00:05.361506
# Key: 'caJ8ArNRvefgdfgbdhfdbfdbf' | Cannot flip key due to  
# feature1 being enabled
# Key: 'caixF0Nmdfjdfdbfdgdbgdnmjdfs' | Cannot flip key due to  
# feature1 being enabled
# Total keys: 22 | Keys that Application can serve: 20 | Keys that Application can't serve: 2
# Execution finished. Total time: 0:00:33.796226
# client:"B"
# Total number of keys discovered: 13
# Execution finished. Total time: 0:00:05.539271
# Total keys: 13 | Keys that Application can serve: 13 | Keys that Application can't serve: 0
# Execution finished. Total time: 0:00:20.573984
```

Then you can use `awk` and run this line to get the output you want.

```sh
awk 'BEGIN { FS = ":" } /client/ { print $2 } /serve/ { print $NF }' output.txt > client.txt
cat client.txt
# "A"
#  2
# "B"
#  0
```

Then you can use the `client.txt` file and read it into Python with something like this.

```py
with open('client.txt') as fh:
    for line in fh.readlines():
        print(line.replace('\"', '').strip())
# A
# 2
# B
# 0
```